# How execute SQL file and inserting data into DATABASE TABLES using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL file which i created from another database (named as `test`) on my localhost and now i want to insert this data into another database ( named as `server_db`) via PHP Script .

I tried and my PHP Script is working fine and creating the tables into `server_db` database. 
But values in those tables are not inserting ..... Please Help

### My PHP Code is given below

```
<?php 
class Executer {
   public $path=""; 
   public function execute($path){
    // MySql connectivity
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("server_db");

    //file content
    $content = file_get_contents($path);

    //remove the comments
    $lines = explode("\n",$content);
    $content = '';

    foreach($lines as $line){
        $line = trim($line);
        if( $line && !$this->startsWith($line,'--') ){
            $content .= $line . "\n";
        }
    }
    //convert data into array of queries
    $content = explode(";", $content);
    //run the query
    $total = $sucess=0;
    foreach($content as $command){
        if(trim($command)){
            $success = (mysql_query($command)==false ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }
}
public function startsWith($string, $sym_com){
    $length = strlen($sym_com);
    return (substr($string, 0, $length) === $sym_com);
}   


} $path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/downloads/server_database_file.sql";
execute($path);
```

Comment: Using command line Select database then source <file path><file name>. It will faster

Comment: also, please have a look at PDO

Comment: There is an extra curly brace here `} $path`

Comment: You could use `file()` instead of exploding by `\n`. What do you get if you `var_dump($content)`? Instead of `explode(';'...`) you may want to check if the last character of a line is ';', indicating a proper end of statement, rather than any one of the possible semicolons in your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your SQL text file encoding. because the line delimiter for each encoding is not always `"\n"`. You can try change with `"\r"`

Comment: thanks @Helmi Joe i will try it . once again thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you on localhost you can use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function with [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

```
exec('mysqldump server_database > C:/xampp/htdocs/final/downloads/server_database_file.sql')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just wrote it up, realizing I didn't have a function for this. You need to verify that `;` is the last character of a line, exploding by `;` can lead to false mid-data splits. Below approach simply buffers the lines up until it finds a terminating `;`, then inserts them into an array and resets the buffer.

```
function parse_sql_file($filepath) {

    $queries = [];
    $sql_query = [];
    $lines = file($filepath);

    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        // This is a comment: move on, nothing to see here.
        if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--') continue;

        $sql_query[] = $line;

        // We found a terminator: do the needful.
        if (substr($line, -1) == ';') {
            $queries[] = trim( implode("\n", $sql_query) );
            $sql_query = [];
        }
    }

    return $queries;
}

$queries = parse_sql_file('my.sql');
var_dump($queries);
```